# SPARQL CONSTRUCT; not all results are retrieved

Tags: sparql, blazegraph, wikidata-query-service

I am tying to construct an RDF graph containing films and their labels on [Wikidata SPARQL query service](https://query.wikidata.org). 
Basically, this is the query I thought would be sufficient:

```
CONSTRUCT{
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  ?film rdfs:label ?filmLabel.
}
WHERE{
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

It seems like not all films appear in the results (127636 results), what I note is that the films which don't appear are basically the ones without labels.

However, a `SELECT` query for the same information returns more results (215734):

```
SELECT ?film ?filmLabel
WHERE{
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". 
  }
}
```

It seems like not all variables bindings meeting the `WHERE` clause (the `WHERE` clause is shared between both queries) are used in the `CONSTRUCT` at the first query, but all of them are used in the `SELECT`.

Why is that? Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure that any label will be returned in a CONSTRUCT query? It's a "magic" feature of Blazegraph, and beyond standard SPARQL.

Comment: No I am not; I think this is basically the issue. According to Construct specification, it should, however, be okay https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug somewhere in the `CONSTRUCT` optimizer and is not related to the label service.

Possible workarounds are these Blazegraph [hints](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints):

- `hint:Query hint:queryEngineChunkHandler "Managed"`
- `hint:Query hint:constructDistinctSPO false`

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#CONSTRUCT%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424.%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FfilmLabel.%0A%7D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20%23%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3AqueryEngineChunkHandler%20%22Managed%22%20.%0A%20%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3AconstructDistinctSPO%20false%20.%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D)

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  ?film rdfs:label ?filmLabel .
}
WHERE { 
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  hint:Query hint:queryEngineChunkHandler "Managed" .
  # hint:Query hint:constructDistinctSPO false .  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

Comment: that's an odd issue by the way, couldn't find a GH issue. Thanks for showing workarounds - although It looks like `hint:Query hint:queryEngineChunkHandler "Managed" .` did not work for all my queries, so I stick to `hint:Query hint:constructDistinctSPO false .  ` and will live with  deduplication afterwards (or leave it to the triple store)